# Issues using compose to create a wanted layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to achieve the layout shown on the image. These are the folowing requirements

- Section A has fixed height
- Section C should always be fully visible and showing all possible items
- Section B should adjust its height in order for C to have all its children visible. However, the maximum height it can have is the same as the width of the device

[Layout of the views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPGB5.png)

I tried using Column with a constraint layout. The problem with the code posted below is that the data in the ViewB is always aligned to the bottom when the screen is bigger. I don't want this

```
Column(modifier = modifier) {
      
        Header()
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            val (viewC, viewB) = createRefs()

            ViewB(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(viewB){
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
            )
            ViewC(
                modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(viewC){
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(viewB.top)

                    height = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }
            )

        }
    }
```